# Add attribute to root element generated by FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have looked around and I have found a few samples but it does not make a lot of sense to me currently. I'm trying to add a attribute to the root. One sample I did see suggested using a temp table which kind of makes sense but still a little muddy.

Here is my current query:

```
    DECLARE
@inv_code nvarchar(100)
--as
if (isnull(@inv_code,'')<>'' or ISNUMERIC(@inv_code)=1)
begin
    SELECT  
        net_inv_code,--11/21/2018 MAH 
        net_ivd_key=ivd_key, 
        net_ivd_price=convert(decimal(9,2),ivd_price), 
        net_ivd_qty=convert(decimal(9,2),ivd_qty), 
        net_ivd_amount_cp=convert(decimal(9,2),linetotal), 
        net_prc_display_name=prd_name, 
        ivd_order=CASE WHEN ivd_prc_prd_ptp_key = '1E30F230-3750-4747-8ACC-36F50B5CC610' THEN '100000' ELSE lineNumber END,  
        net_tracking_number=trackingNumber, 
        net_prc_code=prc_code, 
        net_linebalance, 
        net_fws_ptp_type=ivd_prc_prd_ptp_key, 
        [status], ivd_prc_prd_key 
    FROM vw_client_aha_ac_invoice_detail_integrated  
    WHERE net_inv_code=@inv_code
    ORDER BY ivd_order
    for xml path('ivd'), root('inv net_inv_code=' + @inv_code)
end
else
begin
    select 
        null as net_inv_code,--11/21/2018 MAH
        null as ivd_key,
        null as net_ivd_price,
        null as net_ivd_qty,
        null as net_ivd_amount_cp,
        null as net_prc_display_name,
        null as ivd_order,
        null as net_tracking_number,
        null as net_prc_code,
        null as net_linebalance,
        null as net_fws_ptp_type,
        null as [status],
        null as ivd_prc_prd_key
        for xml path('ivd'), root('inv')
end
```

I've tried adjusting this line:

```
for xml path('ivd'), root('inv net_inv_code=' + @inv_code)
```

I assume you cant edit that path like I had hoped. This is what Im trying to get to return:

```
<inv net_inv_code="1001538">
<ivd>
    <net_inv_code>1001538</net_inv_code>
    <net_ivd_key>74A440ED-8CF6-4D57-8362-6EBC97CB8221</net_ivd_key>
    <net_ivd_price>0.00</net_ivd_price>
    <net_ivd_qty>0.00</net_ivd_qty>
    <net_ivd_amount_cp>0.00</net_ivd_amount_cp>
    <net_prc_display_name>SHSMD U 2018 | Healthcare Marketing Credential: Marketing Plans, Communications &amp; Market Research</net_prc_display_name>
    <net_prc_code>309HMC2018-M</net_prc_code>
    <net_linebalance>0.0000</net_linebalance>
    <net_fws_ptp_type>64B77FB4-DA34-4034-ADA8-F1DA796D8720</net_fws_ptp_type>
    <ivd_prc_prd_key>EE4DFB27-3171-4463-B300-1DDCBB71D877</ivd_prc_prd_key>
</ivd>
<ivd>
    <net_inv_code>1001538</net_inv_code>
    <net_ivd_price>0.00</net_ivd_price>
    <net_ivd_qty>0.00</net_ivd_qty>
    <net_ivd_amount_cp>0.00</net_ivd_amount_cp>
    <ivd_order>99999</ivd_order>
    <net_prc_code>Tax</net_prc_code>
    <net_linebalance>0.0000</net_linebalance>
    <net_fws_ptp_type>F53B02CB-7623-49B4-A59A-55B0547F291C</net_fws_ptp_type>
</ivd>
```

​

Currently I have a syntax error. Looking for the best/easiest solution

Update:
Based on your suggestion here is what I have tried but getting syntax errors:

```
    SELECT @inv_code AS '@net_inv_code', 
(
    SELECT  
        net_inv_code,--11/21/2018 MAH 
        net_ivd_key=ivd_key, 
        net_ivd_price=convert(decimal(9,2),ivd_price), 
        net_ivd_qty=convert(decimal(9,2),ivd_qty), 
        net_ivd_amount_cp=convert(decimal(9,2),linetotal), 
        net_prc_display_name=prd_name, 
        ivd_order=CASE WHEN ivd_prc_prd_ptp_key = '1E30F230-3750-4747-8ACC-36F50B5CC610' THEN '100000' ELSE lineNumber END,  
        net_tracking_number=trackingNumber, 
        net_prc_code=prc_code, 
        net_linebalance, 
        net_fws_ptp_type=ivd_prc_prd_ptp_key, 
        [status], ivd_prc_prd_key 
    FROM vw_client_aha_ac_invoice_detail_integrated  
    WHERE net_inv_code=@inv_code
    ORDER BY ivd_order
) AS v
FOR XML PATH('ivd'), TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH('inv')
```

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** and not covered by the ANSI/ISO SQL standard - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query:

```sql
DECLARE @inv_code VARCHAR(100) = '1001538';

SELECT TRY_CAST(@inv_code AS INT) AS '@net_inv_code', (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (1001538, 'x'),
        (1001538, 'x')
    ) AS v(net_inv_code, net_ivd_key)
    FOR XML PATH('ivd'), TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH('inv')
```

[Produces the following result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=34704919d9bad7cc2c0ecfa3fc4764bc):

```xml
<inv net_inv_code="1001538">
    <ivd>
        <net_inv_code>1001538</net_inv_code>
        <net_ivd_key>x</net_ivd_key>
    </ivd>
    <ivd>
        <net_inv_code>1001538</net_inv_code>
        <net_ivd_key>x</net_ivd_key>
    </ivd>
</inv>
```

Which seems to be what you're looking for. The `net_inv_code` attribute will **not** be added if `@inv_code` is not an integer.

Comment: TRY_CAST is not a built in function. Yes this is what I'm trying to get but I'm sorry the code suggested is very different then the original and does not make a lot of since to also the function your referencing does not exist. I'm trying to make as few changes as possible to get the query to work. Also it looks like your hard coding some values. Not sure if that's for reference or not in your query

Comment: TRY_CAST is available in SQL 2012+. You could use ISNUMERIC instead (but it is very naive). Basically, you need to supply NULL if you do not want the attribute present. And yes, you're supposed to place your original query instead of `VALUES`.

Comment: Updated based on original suggestion

Comment: See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f5fbfaa3b9f43ccfa011217d20b186e (just the syntax errors and "top" issue removed)

Comment: I already posted the correct and working code. It is up to you to adapt. Thanks.